# Dart Unhandled Exception: Connection failed, stack trace: #0 IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:88:7)

Tags: flutter, dart

im new in flutter and i want to consume my Api to display data in my app ,
i made this in service class :

```
class Service {
  final String apiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/Todo";

  
  Future<List<Todo>> getCases() async {
    Response res = await get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(res.body);
      List<Todo> todo = body.map((dynamic item) => Todo.fromJson(item)).toList();
      return todo;
    } else {
      throw "Failed to load cases list";
    }
  }
```

the Terminal shows me that there is an error in `Response res = await get(Uri.parse(apiUrl));`

**The Error**

```
[ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: Connection failed, stack trace: #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:88:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Service.getCases (package:restnv/Service/service.dart:11:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _FutureBuilderState._subscribe.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:627:33)
```

**NB**
i get my Api from Npm json-server

how can i fix it

Comment: have you try to use ip adrress . change the `localhost`

Comment: same probleme, , i changed it to 127.0.0.1 and change

Answer (score 1):

This problem might be because of your local host

```
//final String ApiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/Todo"
```

This will not work in physical devices, so you should try local host to

> 10.0.2.2:3000

This will work in emulator.